# generate dynamic dropdown menu inside jQuery append

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have dynamic table generated via `jQuery` using `append`.
The first row contains table `header`. Second contains input fields (text fields, dropdown menu's etc). 
Third and others contains table content.

```
 $el.append('<tr>
                 <td>ID</td>\n\
                 <td>Name</td>\n\
                 <td>Something</td>\n\
                 <td>Something</td>\n\
                 <td>Something</td>\n\
                 <td></td>\n\
                 <td></td>\n\
                 <td></td>\n\
             </tr>\n\
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <input name="test-id" id="test-id" class="machine_management" maxlength="5"  type="hidden"/>
                 </td>\n\
                 <td></td>\n\
                 <td></td>\n\
                 <td>HERE MENU</td>\n\
                 <td></td>\n\
                 <td></td>\n\
                 <td></td>\n\
                 <td></td>\n\
             </tr>\n\
');
```

and `ajax({ // generate table content});`

My problem is that i don't know how to create dynamic `dropdown` menu inside `row 2`( HERE MENU).
Any ideas? I believe should be another `ajax` call inside? this `append`? Or create variable and add these values as a long string (`variable` = `variable + value`;) and then post in `row 2`?
I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: What exactly should the dropdown menu look like? Is it also dynamic content? Question is unclear.

Comment: @vyx.ca values loaded from database `<option value="name1" >Name1</option>` etc

Comment: Do these values change over time or are they static on page load?

Comment: Yes. Values are not static. need to pull these values from db

Answer (score 0):

Your `HERE MENU` is going to need to be replaced with a `<select>` list.  If you try to do it using nested AJAX calls, you are just looking for headaches - as you've guessed, you want to do a separate AJAX call, create the string in a variable, and insert it instead of your place-holder.